# UV Unwrapping problems

Tags: uv

Im trying to make a simple shelf but it doesnt want to UV Unwrap properly, and i dont know what im doing wrong.

Here is an image of the faces that doesnt want to work, as you can see the dot indicating where the middle of the face is is to the side on the selected ones, not in the middle.
[image: Faces that doesnt want to unwrap properly]

At first i thought maybe filling in these would help, but it doesnt [image: Filling these holes doesnt help]

This is how the unwrap looks

[image: This is how the unwrap looks]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all four of your faces have more than four vertices, perhaps because of duplicate vertices. Do eliminate these, in edit mode, press "W > remove doubles". If this is not it, then it's likely that the four faces marked for unwrapping are n-gons. The likelihood is that the faces with the off center face selection dots are the offenders.

Comment: I tried removing doubles, didnt work. Edit: The problem was more than 4 verts, if i select the top 2 and bottom 2 anf then fill the gap the UV works, thanks :)